# How do I add a class to a link in a bootstrap's popover?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, haml

```
      %ul.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right
        %li
          %a{:href => "#", "data-content" => "<a href='#' class='c'>New</a><br />Outbound<br/>Inbound<br/>", "data-toggle" => "popover", "data-placement" => "bottom", "data-trigger" => "focus", "data-html" => "true","data-animation" => "true"}
```

The code snippet above is from the nav bar, and as you can tell, it's in HAML.

If I just added `class c` like this `:class => 'c'`, it works, but it affects the entire popover.

I'd like it just to work on at least in `New` anchor only for now.

How do I make it work just on `New`?

Thank you.

**Edited out the jquery code as that's distracting from the question. I just want to know how to be able to add class to a specific link in bootstrap's popover**

**Edit 2**

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.testing4').hide();
                $('.navbar').on('click', 'a.c' function() 
                {
                    $('.testing3, .testing4').toggle()
                    return false;
                }
            );
        });
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understood. Try adding 'return false;' after $('').toggle();

Comment: @AramilRey, um, I'm guessing that adding `return false` would prevent it working? That's not the issue here. The issue is that I'm trying to add a `class c` to `New` link in the bootstrap's popover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I'm going out on a limb and assume that you have an event listener listening to `click` on a link with class `c`? If so the reason why your listener isn't being trigger is because when you first call it the popover isn't generated. What I would recommend is adding the `event listener` to a parent element. i.e.

```
$('.navbar-nav').on('click', 'a.c', function () {
  // do stuff here
});
```

You're relying on event delegation to bubble up that event to `.navbar-nav`

Comment: hey, just saw your answer a few minutes ago. I tried it and it didn't work. I've put it in the post above. I really don't understand why if the class `c` is put in the overall popover, it works, but the minute I try to put it in a single line, i.e, `New`, it doesn't work.

Comment: @devkarou, never mind what I said previously. Turns out your answer does work. I just inadvertently left out a comma between 'a.c', and function. Oops! Thank you for your answer. It actually worked!

Comment: thank you so much! based on what you said, I finallly figured out how to get content rendered, albeit slightly differently, but it shows up! Thank you. Thank you. Thank you. This is in reference to the other post that I've deleted since then. But thank you so much! I really needed to solve it tonight.

Answer (score 0):

So, the click function works fine, but the a inside needs to have '.c'?

Maybe

```
$('li > a').find('a').addClass('c');
```

or change the href of the inner  and use:

```
$('a[href^="anotherlink"]').addClass('c');
```

Is that the question?

Comment: thanks for your answer. Appreciate it. But the reason why I had originally added `'class c` in the link is that so it would trigger the jquery snippet that I had originally posted. And for some reason the 'class c` in the inner `a` of `New` doesn't work. That's the issue here. Trying to get that `class c` to work so it can trigger the jquery.